# In 'unless', how would've 'negative connotation' caused 'on' to change to 'un'?

Tags: etymology, unless

> [unless (conj.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/unless)
>
> mid-15c., earlier *onlesse*,
> from ***(not)** on lesse (than)* "**(not)** on a less compelling condition (than);" see [less](https://www.etymonline.com/word/less?ref=etymonline_crossreference).
> The first syllable originally [on](https://www.etymonline.com/word/on?ref=etymonline_crossreference), but `the negative connotation` and the lack of stress changed it to *un-*. "*Except* could once be used as a synonym for *unless*, but the words have now drawn entirely apart" [Century Dictionary].

I ask about only one determinant of change:  `the negative connotation`. 1. How'd it cause 'on' to change, when the negative connotation is wholly spwaned by 'less'?

2. To a Middle English layperson, wouldn't prefixing 'less' with 'un' reverse the meaning of 'unless'?  As 'less than good = not good', wouldn't

> un + less than good
> = not + not good
> = good?

Comment: ON is just the way they used to spell what we spell UN. Spelynge hath y-changed.

Comment: @JohnLawler If so, then would Etymonline be wrong to impute 'the negative connotation' to this prefix change?

Comment: I have no idea what they mean by "the negative connotation". The prefix is negative, that's all. No connotation involved.

Comment: @JohnLawler The prefix used to be the preposition _on_, which is not negative. At some point, the general negative connotations of the phrase/word caused the prefix to shift from the preposition _on_ to the negating prefix _un-_. Spelling is not the essential part here; _un-_ has been written that way since Old English, generally distinct from _on-_.

Comment: In some dialects. In others, other things happened. Similar remarks famously apply to _black_ and _blank_, which meant 'black' and 'white', but not necessarily in that order, all through Middle English times -- dialects and idiolects varied a great deal in which meant which.

Comment: Just a note that in Middle English several prepositions were used with "les(se) (than)" to mean "unless" - in, of, o, and upon. ([MED](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary?per_page=100&search_field=anywhere)).

Answer (score 1):

This is almost a form of rebracketing-- in which a word's roots are re-defined by misunderstanding, like alcoholic (which has roots in al-kohl and the suffix -ic, but was rebracketed as alco-holic, allowing for the suffix -holic to appear in words like workaholic or coffeeholic)-- crossed with a mondegreen-- a mishearing leading to respelling, like eggcorn for acorn, or like in the game Telephone. As the prefix on- became relatively obsolete and the phonetically-similar prefix un- gained popularity, the on- in onless got redefined as un-, incorrectly. This is an example of a false etymology.